# Rotating disc with viscous damping with large initial angle (always 90 degrees) (unbalance/instability)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, stability, dissipation

I have an application for a rotating disc with inertia that is put on a "knife edge" balancing fixture. The disc is then released in order to find the "heavy spot", once identified the point is rotated for 90 degrees and is released again. I record the angles with respect to time. What I've found is that I'm dealing with exponential decay according to $$y(t)=y_0*e^(-\beta*t)*cos(\omega*t)$$ omega being $$\omega=\sqrt(\omega_0^2-\beta^2)$$ and I can fit the data reasonablly well in first 2-3 oscilations (an oscilation for me is the path from one extreme to another and back) and then the equation and data diverges. The peaks of first few oscilations of recorded data and with equation are almost equal but if I look at half oscilation of the first "swing" or in general the negative amplitude part of the diagram, the data if off. What I think I'm missing is correction for large amplitudes and I'm struggling with mathematics of it. Is there some simplification to be made to account the starting point of rotation being at exactly 90 degrees?
The reason for my setup is finding the unbalance of rotating discs, which I can do with the equations above, but still I would like to go one step further- another quiet wish is to do have strong mathematics to account for arbitrary (but known) starting angle and to be able to extract unbalance.